# Meaning of 'pis'

Tags: sens

I've searched online for this, but I keep coming up with 'worst' (i.e. the superlative of 'bad') as the meaning which doesn't seem to fit in the following example:

> "N'est-ce pis là une phrase typique de ceux qui aiment plaindre?"

So, what does '*pis*' mean in this sentence, and how does this usage relate to the standard meaning of 'worst' that appears in French-English dictionaries?

Comment: http://offqc.com/2014/10/27/using-the-informal-pis-la-in-quebecois-french-when-telling-a-story-871/

Comment: @rsanchez interesting link, but the question above doesn't begin with _pis là_ and it appears as a single thought, rather than an element of a story.

Comment: Could you bring some context, such as where you have seen this sentence for example? The answer if this is old French might be different for modern French, for instance. In a modern context, I'd have in mind that this is just a typo for « _pas_ » (or [a variant of « _puis_ »](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pis#Adverbe_2) but I've never seen it used in an interrogative form that way).

Comment: This "N'est-ce pis là..." cannot be anything else than a typo or an OCR mistake for the obvious "N'est-ce pas là...".

Comment: Following @jlliagre point of view: as a stand alone word, "pis" was used in old French as "Pire"(worst), it is currently used as a synonym to "Et"(and) in Québec familiar language. Though, within this sentence, it can really only be a typo from "p**a**s"(not).

Comment: @Sifu "Pis" is still present in French expressions like "de mal en pis", "un pis aller", "tant pis".

Comment: I also think that it is a typo. Furthermore the end of the sentence also sounds weird, which makes me more confident that the writer of this phrase should not be taken as an example. I would write : "N'est-ce PAS là une phrase typique de ceux qui aiment SE plaindre?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The beginning of your sentence is wrong and would rather be: "N'est-ce pas là..."

But to answer your question, pis has 2 meanings in French:

- worst (but it's kinda old french and "pire" is preferred)
- a cow's udder

Comment: Could also encounter it as a slang version of `puis` : "Et pis c'est tout !", other usages in the comments to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I think the correct word is *pas* (*Isn't it there a typical sentence of those who like complaining?*).

*pis* comes from the latin *pejor*, which means *worse*. In general, if you can say *pis*, you can replace it by *pire* (the usual French word for *worse*). I personally encountered that word in expressions, and occasionally in old books: no one uses it outside of expressions. The grammar guide precises that the word can be used both as an adjective or as a noun.

Reference: [Le français correct: Guide pratique des difficultés](https://books.google.ch/books?id=Cva6FlQ-5nYC&pg=PA207&lpg=PA207&dq=pis%20petit%20robert&source=bl&ots=9hxaap3GU8&sig=RA6ABvWf6Q0Jp-r81wRC8tKmQDs&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNmrCu1bDJAhUHWBQKHRWLDOoQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=pis%20petit%20robert&f=false)

> *Pis* (du latin *pejus*, neutre de *pejor*) est le comparatif de supériorité de *mal*: *Cela ne va ni mieux ni pis qu'avant* (Petit Robert). - Excepté dans certaines expressions, *pis* est concurrencé par *plus mal* et par *pire*.
>
> *Pis* et *pire* s'utilisent comme adjectifs ou comme noms. (...)